# stringgrid columnname insert date and day info

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am doing this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var dtStart: TDateTime;
  I: Integer;
begin
  dtStart := DateTimePicker1.Date;
  for I := 0 to 6 do
    StringGrid1.Cells[I+1, 1] := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', dtStart + I);
end;
```

Any way to add the name of the day together with the date i.e like MON TUE WED etc

Comment: You can find examples of several date formats e.g. [`here`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Dates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your `FormatDateTime` format string:

```
StringGrid1.Cells[I+1, 1] := FormatDateTime('ddd dd/mm/yyyy', dtStart + I);
```

Comment: If you add more d's, you would get the date added by default and would not have to worry about day/month order yourself. Window's short date format takes 5 d's strung together, long date needs 6.

Comment: I know. :) That's not what the question asked, though; it asked to add the short day name (eg., MON TUE WED) in front of the date, which is what I answered.

Comment: I know. :) That's why it is a comment. Just so if people are interested, they know about it.

Comment: works like charm but is it possible to have the letters in capital i.e like MON TUE WED ? Now I am getting mon tue wed ....

Comment: I did :AdvStringGrid1.Cells[I+1, 0] := uppercase(FormatDateTime('DD/MM/YYYY    DDD', dtStart + I));kinda works ...thanks